# SQL Concurrent transactions with SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

i have transaction which looks like this:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT last_table_row;
...some long queries with last_table_row data...
DELETE selected_last_table_row;
COMMIT;
```

if i run this transaction twice at same time second one will use same last_table_row item as first transaction (tried from psql console) which is not desired. How should i handle this type of transaction to be safe and not having interfering transactions?

Comment: You'll need to give some sort of hint as to what "last_table_row" is supposed to be. Are you trying to process a queue of items?

Comment: Yes, something like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SELECT FOR UPDATE.

> If FOR UPDATE, FOR NO KEY UPDATE, FOR SHARE or FOR KEY SHARE is specified, the SELECT statement locks the selected rows against concurrent updates.

[Here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) is the documentation on `The Locking Clause`.

Answer (score 1):

As well as SELECT FOR UPDATE, considering you'll remove that row at the end of the transaction, you may as well remove it at the beginning copying into a temporary table:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMP TABLE last_table_row ON COMMIT DROP AS
  WITH ltr AS (
    DELETE FROM yourtable
    WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM yourtable)
    RETURNING *)
  SELECT * FROM ltr;

...some long queries with last_table_row data...
COMMIT;
```